se puede crear una cantidad i de elementos de una clase, siendo i el contador de un bucle for? todo en javascript
El ejercicio es el siguiente: crear una clase "Colegio" y una clase "Estudiante" en javascript. Para hacer la carga, pensando que puede haber varios alumnos y por ende el proceso de carga se repetiria varias veces, tuve la idea de crear tantos estudiantes como valor tenga i dentro del bucle (por ejemplo, asi):
for (i=0;i<=numeroAlumnos;i++){
const nombreEstudiante=prompt("¿Nombre completo?");
const dni=prompt("¿DNI del estudiante?");
const estudiante(i)=new Estudiante(nombreEstudiante, dni);
}


Existen los array que son elementos que te sirven para almacenar otros elementos.
Piénsalo como casilleros, donde en cada casillero almacenas un elemento. Y a su vez cada casillero tiene un índice, que va desde el cero hasta el largo del array menos 1.

const estudiantes = new Array(numeroAlumnos); // creas un array, opcionalmente con un largo predeterminado
for (i=0;i<=numeroAlumnos;i++){
  const nombreEstudiante=prompt("¿Nombre completo?");
  const dni=prompt("¿DNI del estudiante?");
  estudiantes[i] = new Estudiante(nombreEstudiante, dni); //asignas un estudiando al casillero 'i' del array
}


genial, estuve viendo eso pero no sabia como usarlo exactamente. Funciona sin problema aun cuando el array no tiene un tamaño definido?
class Colegio { constructor(nombre, numeroAulas, numeroAlumnos) {     this.nombre = nombre;     this.numeroAulas = numeroAulas;     this.numeroAlumnos = numeroAlumnos;     this.estudiantes = [];   }

Estos elementos para guardar se llaman "estructuras de datos", existen muchos tipos. Los array son (en general) fijos en su tamaño, las listas son parecidas, pero con un tamaño dinámico, también existen las pilas y las colas y otros muchos (arboles, grafos, etc). Todo esto en términos generales, pero pasa que en javascript un array es array y a su vez es también lista, cola y pila (todo en uno). Entonces, en javascript, no es necesario definir el tamaño de un array (porque en ese caso funciona como lista)

Tu pregunta me deja algunas dudas, asi que comienzo de "cero".
Primero dices, crear una clase Colegio y una Estudiante
class Colegio {

   nombre;
   alumnos = [];

   constructor( nom ) {
      nombre = nom;
   }

   getAlumno( legajo ) {
      return xx;
   }

   agregarAlumno( alum ) {
      alumnos.push( alum );
   }
}

class Estudiante {
   dni;
   nombre;
   legajo;

   constructor( dn, nom, leg ) {
      dni = dn;
      nombre = nom;
      legajo = leg;
   }
   
   // getters y setters
}

  // creamos el colegio
let escuela = new Colegio( "Escuela de programación Popo" );
let numeroAlumnos = 3;

for( let i = 0; i < = numeroAlumnos; i++ ) {   
   let nombreEstudiante = prompt( "¿Nombre completo?" );
   let dni = prompt( "¿DNI del estudiante?" );
   let estudiante = new Estudiante( nombreEstudiante, dni, i );
     // es necesario agregar el alumno al colegio
   escuela.agregarAlumno( estudiante );
}

Hasta acá, es más o menos lo que presentaste, me parece pertinente, plantear otra forma de crear los alumnos:
data = [
   [ "Edelmiro Molinari", 12.321.543 ]
   [ "Adalberto Goncalvez", 9.543.989 ]
   [ "Sacarías Sosa, 11.432.763 ]
];

for( int i = 0; i < numeroAlumnos; i++ ) {
   escuela.agregarAlumno( new Estudiante( data[ 0 ], data[ 1 ], i );
}

En la misma linea, creamos el alumno y lo agregamos en el colegio.
Podes ver que no creamos una variable alumno, ya que no la vamos a usar, cuando querramos hacer algo con un alumno, se lo pedimos al colegio con getAlumno( numeroLegajo ), función que deje incompleta...
